# NoHostAvailableException when Cassandra Embedded is used

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, junit5, spring-data-cassandra

I have a spring boot application that uses spring-data-cassandra. I'm trying to write integration test for this application by using embedded Cassandra.

Here are the dependencies I used:

```
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
       exclude group: 'junit'
   }
   testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.2")
   testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.2")
   testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.23.4")
   testCompile group: 'org.cassandraunit', name: 'cassandra-unit-spring', version: '3.5.0.1'
```

Here is the test code:

```
import org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraDataSet;
import org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener;
import org.cassandraunit.spring.EmbeddedCassandra;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners(
        listeners = CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
        mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
@CassandraDataSet(value = "dataset.cql", keyspace = "key_space")
@EmbeddedCassandra
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

However, when I run the application I got the following error:

`com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException`

Which means that the default Cassandra embedded configuration didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert with `cassandra-unit`, but I can propose you an alternative library: https://github.com/nosan/embedded-cassandra

```
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedCassandra(scripts = "...", replace = EmbeddedCassandra.Replace.NONE /*use auto-configured cluster */)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class EmbeddedCassandraTests {

    @Test
    public void testMe() {

    }

}
```

Hope, it would help you.

Comment: @Dymtro Thanks. Yeah, I saw this library, but I didn't want to use it because it's not an official one from Cassandra.